# Why do I get a "HTTP load failed" exception after upgrading to XCode 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios8, xcode7

My project worked fine with XCode 6 targeting iOS 7.0. Now I upgraded to XCode 7 targeting iOS 8.0 and I get the following error repeatedly:

> 2015-09-19 16:40:14.794 MyProject[624:138018]
>   NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)

The app doesn't start anymore and I am just facing a black screen.

To my knowledge I don't initiate any HTTP connections, except for the Facebook integration for which I had to set up an URL type (but I already uncommented all related code and removed the URL scheme, still the same problem).

Any ideas how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple introduced App Transport Security (ATS) with iOS 9. Here is the according [Apple's technote about ATS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/). Download the latest Facebook SDK and add the exceptions (whitelist Facebook servers) to your Info.plist file as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started) and try it again.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was indeed the Facebook SDK.